multinomial covariance matrix is singular?
Consider a multinomial distribution, $\text{multinom}\left(n, \left(p_1,\dots, p_k\right)\right)$. There is a $k\times k$ covariance matrix, $\Sigma$, that depends on the parameters of the multinomial distribution. Diagonal entry $\Sigma_{i,j} = np_i(1 - p_i)$, and off-diagonal entry $i, j$ is equal to $-np_ip_j$.
So far, so good. Let's do some calculations using this idea.
multinomial_sigma <- function(n, p){
  
  k <- length(p)
  
  cov_np <- matrix(NA, k, k)
  for (i in 1:k){
    for (j in 1:k){
      
      if (i == j){
        cov_np[i, j] <- n * p[i] * (1 - p[j])
      }
      if (i != j) {
        cov_np[i, j] <- -n * p[i] * p[j]
      }
    }
  }
  return(cov_np)
}

s <- multinomial_sigma(1, c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25))
det(s)

I get that the determinant is zero, so the covariance matrix is singular. No matter what parameters I pass in, I get a singular covariance matrix.
set.seed(2024)
R <- 100
dets <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  k <- sample(seq(3, 7, 1), 1)
  n <- sample(seq(1, 10, 1), 1)
  p <- runif(k, 0, 1); p <- p/sum(p)
  s <- multinomial_sigma(n, p)
  dets[i] <- det(s)
}
summary(dets) # All on the order of 10^-15 or 10^-16, so basically singular

I do not see a bug in my implementation code, so is there something interesting happening, statistically, giving these singular covariance matrices?

See also https://projecteuclid.org/journals/brazilian-journal-of-probability-and-statistics/volume-28/issue-3/The-spectral-decomposition-and-inverse-of-multinomial-and-negative-multinomial/10.1214/12-BJPS213.full

There is a general answer that requires no special calculation and provides insight into how random variables, their distributions, and covariances are inter-related.
Let's begin with some definitions and characterizations of "rank."  The underlying concept is the dimension of a vector or affine subspace of a vector space.  Thus

The rank of a linear transformation is the dimension of its image.

Equivalently, the rank of a matrix is either the dimension of its column space or the dimension of its row space.

The rank of an arbitrary subset $\mathcal S\subseteq \mathbb V$ of a vector space is the dimension of the vector space spanned by all differences $t-s$ where $s\in\mathcal S$ and $t\in\mathcal S.$

The rank of a vector-valued random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb V$ is the smallest possible value of the rank (in sense (3)) of $X(\mathcal E)$ attained among the certain events $\mathcal E$ where $\Pr(\mathcal E)=1.$

Analogously, the rank of a distribution $F$ defined on $\mathbb R^n$ is the rank (in sense (3)) of its support (the smallest closed subset $\mathcal S\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ for which $F(\mathcal S)=1$).


The reason for examining only differences in (3) is to have a definition that is invariant under translation, which is necessary for making any connection with covariances (which themselves are translation-invariant).  Apart from that nicety, all these definitions are conventional.
The generalization is

When $n$ is finite, the ranks of the random variable $X,$ its distribution $F_X,$ and its covariance matrix $\Sigma_X = E[(X-E[X])\,(X-E[X])^\prime]$ are all equal.

Let's get to the punchline before being distracted by a proof.  (The proof nevertheless is of interest because it leads to an intuitive characterization in terms of linear constraints on the random variable $X.$)

Let $X$ have a multinomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $(p_1,\ldots, p_k).$  Then (essentially by definition) $X^\prime \mathbf 1 = n,$ implying the rank of $X$ is at most $k-1.$  Therefore the rank of the covariance matrix of $X$ is at most $k-1.$

Basic facts of linear algebra are that for a square matrix, "rank at most $k-1,$" "singular," "non-trivial kernel (nullspace)," "determinant zero," and "has a zero eigenvalue" are equivalent.  That's why your calculations of the determinant are always zero.

The equality of the ranks of $X$ and $F_X$ is a matter of comparing definitions $(4)$ and $(5).$  What is of interest is the relationship with the rank of the covariance matrix.
The following demonstrates the equivalance of the ranks of $X$ and $\Sigma_X.$  It relies only on the most basic definitions and properties of expectation (linearity, iterated expectation, and "leaving out what is known") and the definition of covariance.
For notational convenience, let $Z = X - E[X]$ be the centered version of $X.$
Consider some nonzero vector $\xi\in\mathbb R^n$ which is almost surely orthogonal to $Z = X-E[X]:$
$$\Pr(Z^\prime\xi = 0) = 1\text{ and (therefore)} \Pr(Z^\prime\xi \ne 0) = 0.$$
This is equivalent to $\Sigma_X\xi=0$ because for any vector $\eta,$
$$\begin{aligned}
\eta^\prime(\Sigma_X\xi) &= \eta^\prime E[ZZ^\prime]\, \xi\\
& = E[\eta^\prime Z\,Z^\prime\xi]\\
&= \Pr(Z^\prime \xi = 0) E[\eta^\prime Z\,Z^\prime\xi\mid Z^\prime \xi = 0] + \Pr(Z^\prime \xi \ne 0) E[\eta^\prime Z\,Z^\prime\xi\mid Z^\prime \xi \ne 0] \\
&= E[\eta^\prime Z\,Z^\prime\xi\mid Z^\prime \xi = 0]\\
&= E[\eta^\prime Z(0)\mid Z^\prime \xi=0]\\
&= 0.
\end{aligned}$$
Conversely, if $\Sigma_X\xi=0,$ then also
$$\begin{aligned}
0 = \xi^\prime\Sigma_X\xi = E[\xi^\prime Z Z^\prime\xi] = E[\|Z^\prime \xi\|^2]
\end{aligned}$$
implies (use Chebyshev) that $Z^\prime\xi=0$ almost surely.
In sum,

$\xi$ is in the kernel (null space) of $\Sigma_X$ if and only if $\xi$ is a linear constraint on $Z:$ that is, $Z^\prime\xi = 0$ almost surely.

Because $n$ is finite, linear algebra tells us the rank of $\Sigma_X$ equals the rank of $Z$ (which is the rank of $X,$ too), qed.

Why does $X^\prime \mathbf 1 = n$ imply the rank of $X$ is at most $k-1?$

$X^\prime\mathbf 1=1$ implies, by linearity of expectation, that $Z^\prime\mathbf 1=0,$ which means the support of $Z$ lies in a codimension-1 subspace. Because subspaces are closed under linear combinations, all differences $t-s$ for $t$ and $s$ in that support also lie in this subspace, qed.

You should have expected this, since for the multinomial distribution $\sum_{i=1}^k X_i = n$, so have variance zero. But let us also show this explicitly, with linear algebra.
Let $\Sigma_0 = \frac1n \Sigma$. Let $X$ be the multinomial vector and $1$ be the vector with all components $1$. Then
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}
  \V\left(\frac1n 1^T X   \right)=\frac1n 1^T \Sigma_0 1
$$
so we just need to calculate the sum of all the components of $\Sigma_0$,  which is
\begin{align}
 \sum_i \sum_j \Sigma_{0ij} &= \sum_j\left( (\sum_{i\not= j}-p_i p_j)+p_j(1-p_j)  \right) \\
  &= \sum_j\left( (\sum_{i\not= j}-p_i p_j)+p_j-p_j p_j)  \right) \\ 
  &= \sum_j\left( (-\sum_i p_i p_j ) +p_j \right) \\
  &= \sum_j\left( -p_j +p_j  \right) = 0
\end{align}
